# Does the relationship between the L function of the elliptic curve and a quadruple series hold?

Tags: elliptic-curves, modular-forms, l-functions

Let $E_{X_0(11)}$ be the elliptic curve (over $\bf Q$) of conductor $11$ defined by
$$y^2+y=x^3-x^2-10x-20.$$

First, some theorems and formulas are introduced as follows.

The modularity theorem (Slow convergence):

\begin{align*}
\displaystyle{}L(E_{X_{0}(11)},1)&=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\dfrac{a(E_{X_{0}(11)})}{n}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\dfrac{a_n(f_{X_{0}(11)})}{n}\\
f(q)=f_{X_{0}(11)}(q)&=q\prod _{k=1}^{+\infty} \left(1-q^k\right)^2 \left(1-q^{11 k}\right)^2\\
f(q)=f_{X_{0}(11)}(q)&=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}a_n(f_{X_{0}(11)})q^n
\end{align*}

The Manin-Drinfeld theorem+BSD formula:
\begin{align*}
L(E_{X_0(11)},1)&=\dfrac{\Omega(E_{X_0(11)})}{5}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{5}\cdot\dfrac{3+\operatorname{sgn}(\Delta(E_{X_0(11)}))}{2}\int_{E_{X_0(11)}(\mathbb{R})}\left|\omega\right|\\
&=\dfrac{1}{5}\int_{E_{X_0(11)}(\mathbb{R})}\dfrac{\mathrm{d}x}{2y+a_1x+a_3}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{5}\int_{E_{X_0(11)}(\mathbb{R})}\dfrac{\mathrm{d}x}{2y+1}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{5}\int_{\alpha}^{+\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{4x^3 - 4x^2 - 40x - 79}} \\
&\\
\alpha&=\tfrac{\small{2+(8-\sqrt{33})(19+3 \sqrt{33})^{1/3}+(8+\sqrt{33})(19-3 \sqrt{33})^{1/3}}}{6} 
\end{align*}

The Cohen formula of L-series (Fast convergence)[Cohen1993, Prop. 7.5.8, p. 405]:

\begin{align*}
L(E_{X_0(11)},1)
&=(1+\varepsilon(E_{X_0(11)}))\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\dfrac{a(E_{X_{0}(11)})}{n}e^{-\frac{2\pi{n}}{\sqrt{N}}}\\
&=2\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\dfrac{a(E_{X_{0}(11)})}{n}e^{-\frac{2\pi{n}}{\sqrt{11}}}\\
\end{align*}

The ODE satisfied by modular parameterization:
\begin{align*}
\frac{f(q)\mathrm{d}q}{q}&=\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{2y + a_1x + a_3} \\
\frac{f(q)\mathrm{d}q}{q}&=\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{2y + 1} \\
\frac{f(q)\mathrm{d}q}{q}&=\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{4x^3 - 4x^2 - 40x - 79}}  \\
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
F=F(q)&=\frac{11 \left(1-24 \sum _{k=1}^{+\infty} \frac{k q^{11 k}}{1-q^{11 k}}\right)-\left(1-24 \sum _{k=1}^{+\infty} \frac{k q^k}{1-q^k}\right)}{10 q \prod _{k=1}^{+\infty} \left(1-q^k\right)^2 \left(1-q^{11 k}\right)^2}+\frac{8}{5}\\
G=G(q)&=\frac{\left(1+240 \sum _{k=1}^{+\infty} \frac{k^3 q^k}{1-q^k}\right)-121 \left(1+240 \sum _{k=1}^{+\infty} \frac{k^3 q^{11 k}}{1-q^{11 k}}\right)}{120 q^2 \prod _{k=1}^{+\infty} \left(1-q^k\right)^4 \left(1-q^{11 k}\right)^4}\\
\\
x=x(q)&=\dfrac{F^2 - 10 F - G + 10}{2}\\
y=y(q)&=\dfrac{10 - 28 F + 15 F^2 - F^3 - 5 G + FG}{2}
\end{align*}
Combining the codes of Mathematica and SageMath, you can verify the specific expression of modular parameterization

```
Column[Series[{(F^2 - 10*F - G + 10)/
     2, (10 - 28*F + 15*F^2 - F^3 - 5*G + F*G)/2} /. 
       {F -> (11*(1 - 
            24*Sum[(k*q^(11*k))/(1 - q^(11*k)), {k, 1, 100}]) - (1 - 
           24*Sum[(k*q^k)/(1 - q^k), {k, 1, 100}]))/
               (10*q*
         Product[(1 - q^k)^2*(1 - q^(11*k))^2, {k, 1, 100}]) + 8/5, 
         
    G -> ((1 + 240*Sum[(k^3*q^k)/(1 - q^k), {k, 1, 100}]) - 
        121*(1 + 240*Sum[(k^3*q^(11*k))/(1 - q^(11*k)), {k, 1, 100}]))/
             (120*q^2*
        Product[(1 - q^k)^4*(1 - q^(11*k))^4, {k, 1, 100}])}, {q, 0, 
   18}]]

E = EllipticCurve('11a1')
phi = E.modular_parametrization()
x,y = phi.power_series(prec=20)
for i in [x, y]:
    print(i)
```

[image: MMA+SageMath]

The following SageMath code can verify this ODE:$\frac{f(q)\mathrm{d}q}{q}=\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{2y + a_1x + a_3}$

```
E = EllipticCurve('11a1')
phi = E.modular_parametrization()
x,y = phi.power_series(prec=20)
a1,_,a3,_,_ = E.a_invariants()
f = E.q_expansion(21)
q = f.parent().gen()
for i in [f/q, (X.derivative()/(2*y+a1*x+a3))]:
    print(i)
```

For this elliptic curve, the module parameterization satisfies the following ODE
\begin{align*}
\frac{f(q)\mathrm{d}q}{q}=\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{2y+1}\tag{e.g.1}
\end{align*}
In addition, according to the long Weierstrass equation of the elliptic curve, we can get the expression of 2y+1:
\begin{align*}
y^2+y&=x^3-x^2-10x-20\\
&\Downarrow\\
\quad{}2y+1&=\sqrt{4x^3 - 4x^2 - 40x - 79}\tag{e.g.2}\\
\end{align*}
According to (e.g.1) and (e.g.2), we can definitely get
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{f(q)}{q}\mathrm{d}q&=\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{4x^3 - 4x^2 - 40x - 79}} 
\end{align*}
The integral on the left hand side of the equal sign is convergent, while the integral on the right hand side of the equal sign, the x value obtained according to the modular parameterization is singular.
Can other modular parameterizations be constructed so that both sides of the following integral relation are regular?
\begin{align*}
\int_{q_1\to0}^{q_2\to1}\dfrac{f(q)}{q}\mathrm{d}q&=\int_{x_1\in\mathbb{R}}^{x_2\in\mathbb{R}}\dfrac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{4x^3 - 4x^2 - 40x - 79}}\quad(\text{Expected situation 1})\\
\int_{q_1\to0}^{q_2\to1}\dfrac{f(q)}{q}\mathrm{d}q&=\int_{x_1\in\mathbb{C}}^{x_2\in\mathbb{C}}\dfrac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{4x^3 - 4x^2 - 40x - 79}}\quad(\text{Expected situation 2})\\
\end{align*}
If the integral is changed to a complex integral, is there an analytical continuation method to obtain the corresponding x value, so that **the integral on the right side of the equal sign can be calculated**, and the x value corresponds to the modular parameter.

> **Question 1**: Can the value of the L function of the elliptic curve $E_{X_0(11)}$ at $s=1$ be equal to an integral, and the coefficient in
> front of the integral is equal to one? According to the modularity
> theorem and the differential equation satisfied by modular
> parameterization, how to determine the integration limit of the above
> integral?
>
> \begin{align*}
>  \displaystyle{}L(E_{X_{0}(11)},1)&=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\dfrac{a_n(f_{X_{0}(11)})}{n}\overset{?}{=}\int_0^1\dfrac{f(q)}{q}\mathrm{d}q\\
>  \int_0^1\dfrac{f(q)}{q}\mathrm{d}q&={\color{red}{1}}\int_{?}^{?}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{4x^3 - 4x^2 - 40x - 79}} \end{align*}
>
> **Question 2**: Can the order of integration and summation here be exchanged? If possible, is this quadruple integral series equal to the
> value of the $L$ function of the elliptic curve $E_{X_0(11)}$ at
> $s=1$?
>
> \begin{align*} L(E_{X_0(11)},1)\overset{?}{=}\dfrac{1}{2}\sum
>  _{(j,k,m,n)\in\mathbb{Z}^4}\dfrac{(-1)^{k+n}}{\scriptsize{(2 j-1)^2+(2 j-1) k+3 k^2+(2 m-1)^2+(2 m-1) n+3 n^2}} \\ 
> \end{align*}

Since the convergence speed of this quadruple series is also extremely slow, it is not certain whether they are equal even if numerical verification is used.
Fortunately, we can show that this infinite product can be expressed as a quadruple series.

\begin{align*}
f(q)&=\dfrac{1}{4}\sum _{(j,k,m,n)\in\mathbb{Z}^4}(-1)^{k+n} q^{\frac{(2 j-1)^2+(2 j-1) k+3 k^2+(2 m-1)^2+(2 m-1) n+3 n^2}{2}}\\
&=q\prod _{k=1}^{+\infty} \left(1-q^k\right)^2 \left(1-q^{11 k}\right)^2
\end{align*}

Ref:

[Cohen1993] H. Cohen. A course in computational algebraic number theory. Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 1993.

[Weston2001] Tom Weston. Modular curves X0(11) and X1(11).

https://swc-math.github.io/notes/files/01Weston1.pdf

Arizona Winter School 2001
Course Descriptions and Notes

https://swc-math.github.io/aws/2001/notes.html#Mazur

https://sites.google.com/view/taweston/home

Comment: I don't understand your question 1.  Sure you can write any number as some integral, and BSD tells you one integral that works.  Maybe you can make your question more concise and direct?

Comment: Dear professor, I have added a more detailed explanation of question 1 and a description of the target results. Hope this can be explained clearly. @Kimball

Comment: I think you’re missing a constant in the integral of $\frac{f(q)}{q}$ compared to $L(E,1)$. Maybe $-i11^{-1/2}$ but I’m not sure.